# Why does RSA fail when p=q

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

A lot of questions about this have unsatisfying answers that either argues how unsafe RSA is when $p=q$ or points out that $\phi(n) \neq (p-1)(q-1)$ for $p=q$.

However, I'd like to know why the RSA fails, i.e why the Decipher $R$ is not equal to the Message $M$ when $p=q$, regardless of safety concerns and **assuming the public and private keys are just blindly computed in modulo $(p-1)(q-1)$.**

Comment: Isn't it enough to say that $\phi(n) \neq (p-1)(q-1)$?  Try encoding and deciphering with $p=q=5$.

Comment: Expanding on @Omnomnomnom's comment, $\phi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)$ for $p\neq q$ (the RSA case), but $\phi(p^2)=p(p-1)$, which is different.  Hence Fermat's Little Theorem will not help in the same way.